# Select last row of table, Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

On this site I found the sql function last ()[LAST()](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_func_last.asp.html)
I used the syntax for Oracle and got a bug.

```
SQL> select symbol from ticker
  2  order by price DESC
  3  where rownum <=1;
where rownum <=1
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I get an error that the command is incorrectly completed even though it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to want this:

```
select t.*
from (select symbol
      from ticker
      order by price DESC
     ) t
 where rownum <= 1;
```

Or in more modern versions of Oracle:

```
select symbol
from ticker
order by price desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Or, if you want to have fun:

```
select max(symbol) keep (dense_rank first order by price desc)
from ticket;
```

The `where` condition goes *before* the `order by`.

Comment: Can you explain why you use `t. *`
And if you can send a link about it

Comment: @petar . . . As opposed to what?  This returns all the columns in `t`.  You can return only the columns that you actually want.